# How can I show an "Add file" button?

Tags: 9

I'm making a form that can update a node values.
I managed to generate a file upload field which shows the already uploaded images, but there's no visible *Add file* button. When I add a new file, the other files disappear.

What should I change in the following code to show an *Add file* button?

```php
$files = $event->field_bijlages;
$fileIds = [];

foreach($files as $file) {
  $fileIds[] = $file->entity->fid->value;
}

/* Files uploading */
$form['files'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#upload_location' => 'public://',
  '#default_value' => $fileIds,
);
```

Normally, a managed_file type field shows the uploaded with a checkbox list which allows you to add/delete uploaded files. That's what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this `#multiple => true` to parameters, since the original field is also a multiple files field. And that made it work!